# JPQL ManyToMany count histogram

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I have following model

### Question

```
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "question_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private List<Tag> tags;

}
```

### Tag

```
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String tagName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private List<Question> question;

}
```

I want to get the histogram of tagName to count of questions per tag with JPQL.

Comment: and what have you tried? There are many JPA documentation sets out there, and they all explain use of JPQL

Comment: @Jack Smith - Could you please share the more requirement ?